# Adding multiple properties to an object shows only the last created prop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add 2 properties to an object depending on some condition:
ex:

```
var data= [
              { name:"Jan", score:4, scale:4 },
              { name:"Feb",score:8, scale:3 },
              { name: "Mar", score:2, scale:9 },
              { name: "Apr", score:10, scale:1 }
]


 data.map(function(point) {    
  if (some condition) {
   point.m = {
    a: 2
   } 
 }else {
   point.m = {
    a: 10
   }
 }
})
//so result in the data im expecting to add the prop `m` of type object to the array.

data = [
                  { name:"Jan", score:4, scale:4,m:{a:2} },
                  { name:"Feb",score:8, scale:3,m:{a:2} },
                  { name: "Mar", score:2, scale:9,m:{a:10} },
                  { name: "Apr", score:10, scale:1,m:{a:2}  }
   ]
```

now on a different scale i want to add another field to prop `m`, im doing:

```
point.m = {
 b: 10 // this value is dynamic so could change.
}
```

so I'm expecting:

```
data = [
                      { name:"Jan", score:4, scale:4,m:{a:2, b:10} },
                      { name:"Feb",score:8, scale:3,m:{a:2, b:10} },
                      { name: "Mar", score:2, scale:9,m:{a:10, b:10} },
                      { name: "Apr", score:10, scale:1,m:{a:2, b:10}  }
       ]
```

but for some reason it only takes the last field added to the prop. I get result as:

```
 data = [
                          { name:"Jan", score:4, scale:4,m:{ b:10} },
                          { name:"Feb",score:8, scale:3,m:{ b:10} },
                          { name: "Mar", score:2, scale:9,m:{ b:10} },
                          { name: "Apr", score:10, scale:1,m:{b:10}  }
           ]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try `point.m.b=10` the way you are doing it will initialize `point.m` again nad hence the result.

Comment: Open up your debugger, and place a breakpoint on the line `point.m = {b: 10}`. When you arrive there, examine `point.m`. Then, after the assignment statement, examine `point.m` again. Then think real hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your example:

```
point.m = {
 b: 10 // this value is dynamic so could change.
}
```

is *replacing* `point.m` with a new object. You want to merge it instead with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```
Object.assign(point.m, { b: 10 })
```

Or, you could simply assign `b` to `m` directly

```
point.m.b = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You are re-writing the property.

```
data.map(function(point) {
  point.m = {};    
  if (some condition) {
    point.m.a = 2;
   } else {
     point.m.a = 10;
   }
  }

  if (some_other_condition) {
    point.m.b = 10;
  }
});
```